# How to override top.links in magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, toplinks

I am trying to override sign in and register link in magento 2. can any one please help me on this.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what do you want to override? It might be a simple xml solution

Comment: i want to make login and register popup.

Answer (score 2):

The top.links can be overriten in defaul.xml of your theme something like:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
           template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

You can see that the AuthorisationLink has a template, you can edit that template to add the popup functionality, also for the "register-link" you can create a template and create desired functionality. Also for the popul functionality check Magento2 Modal component in the devdocs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Comment: i am creating one custom module and override the top.links to add popup.