# Add into Top Link - My Downloadable Products

Tags: magento2, custom, topmenu, toplinks, link

I need to add a link to the top.links block that links to My Downloadable Products and translate it to My Favourite Product, can you tell me if this possible.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be overriden in default.xml in your etc folder like below:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
           template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

reference : [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/148986/91726)